# WARNING: Checking for jobs... failed in docker executer in gitlab-runner

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to run gitlab-ci on a local running using docker executer
This is the config.toml

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
   session_timeout = 1800
   listen_address = "0.0.0.0:8093"

[[runners]]
   url = "https://gitlab.com/<ACCOUNT>/my-static-website"
   token = XXXXXX
   executor = "docker"
   builds_dir = ""
   clone_url = "https://gitlab.com/<ACCOUNT>/my-static-website.git"
   [runners.docker]
     tls_verify = false
     image = "docker:latest"
     privileged = true
     disable_cache = false
     volumes = ["/cache"]
   [runners.cache]
     Insecure = false
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: node

stages:
  - build
  - test

build website:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm install -g gatsby-cli
    - gatsby build
  artifacts:
  paths:
    - ./public
  tags:
    - trials

test artifacts:
  image: alpine
  stage: test
  script:
    - grep -q "Gatsby" ./public/index.html
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux 
pid=28815 revision=4c96e5ad version=12.9.0
Starting multi-runner from ./config.toml...         builds=0
Running in system-mode.

Configuration loaded                                builds=0
listen_address not defined, metrics & debug endpoints disabled  builds=0
Session server listening                            address=0.0.0.0:8093 
builds=0
WARNING: Checking for jobs... failed                runner=kYtFEV-i 
status=404 Not Found
WARNING: Checking for jobs... failed                runner=kYtFEV-i 
status=404 Not Found
WARNING: Checking for jobs... failed                runner=kYtFEV-i 
status=404 Not Found
```

I am using gitlab-runner version 12.9 and gitlab server: 12.10.0-pre
I have my runner on the server as follows:
[image]

I am running the command: gitlab-runner run -c ./config.toml

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 1):

Your runner is not able to check for jobs.  Can you double check the endpoint URL?

If your repository is on gitlab.com, you should be using the endpoint https://gitlab.com/

In your GitLab Web UI, go to **Settings** -> **CI/CD** -> **Runners** -> **Set up a specific Runner manually**

You'll see the endpoint URL and the token you'll need to register your runner.

This is covered in my GitLab CI tutorial at https://gitpitch.com/atsaloli/cicd/master?grs=gitlab#/41 (it takes a few seconds to load)

Let me know if that helps?